# Does the Nintendo Switch count my playtime while a game is running in sleep mode?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I left a game running while I was on the home page when I left my Switch in sleep mode overnight. Was my playtime added?

Comment: This seems to be a rather incredibly easy thing to test.

Answer (score 3):

**No it doesn't.**
I've tested it with Mario Odyssey.